# Liquibase Diff operation not producing output file

Tags: mysql, command-line, diff, command-prompt, liquibase

I'm trying to run a liquibase diff operation on two tables.

The operation appears to work fine as I can see all the comparisons happening in Command Prompt. The only issue I have is that no file is being output. Here's my code, I've added line breaks to help readability:

```
java -jar liquibase/liquibase.jar 
    --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
    --classpath=/liquibase/changelog-generating/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar 
    --changeLogFile=liquibase/local.table.changelog.xml 
        --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/table1" 
        --username=root 
        --password="" 
    diff 
        --referenceUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/table2" 
        --referenceUsername=root 
        --referencePassword=""
```

When I run the command without the diff and reference variables, I do receive an output file.

- Access to the databases work without password (it is only local host after all).
- Liquibase is installed in C:/liquibase
- I'm using Windows Vista

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted. Was missing the...

```
generateChangeLog
```

at the end of the command.